# Constraining a pivot relationship?

Tags: laravel

I have a `drinks` table and a `suppliers` table, there is a many to many relationship between them, with a `drink_supplier` table.

The `drink_supplier` table has an extra field on it called `role`. This is a FK, to a `roles` table. The `roles` table has a `title` field on it.

In Laravel, I wish to write a constrained relationship on the `Drink` model so that I can get the `suppliers` of the `drink` but when the `supplier` acted in a certain `role`.

Drinks

```
id| title
1 | Cola
```

Suppliers

```
id| title     |
1 | Acme Inc. |
```

Roles

```
id| title
1 | Producer
2 | Reseller
```

Drink Supplier

```
drink_id | supplier_id | role_id
1        | 1           | 2
```

Drink Model:

```
public function suppliers(): BelongsToMany {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Suppliers::class)
}

public function resellers(): BelongsToMany
{
     return $this->suppliers()->wherePivot('supplier_role_id', 2);
}
```

The above is fine, but I want to be able to amend the `resellers` relationship, so instead of passing an `int` I can pass the string `Reseller`.

How can I do this inside of the relationship definition?

Comment: Personally, I've never had any success adding a 3rd Model/FK to a `belongsToMany()` relationship. Every time I've tried, I ended up having to refactor it to a `hasMany()`, where (in your case) a `Drink` has many `DrinkSupplierRole` (or whatever you choose to call it) instances, and each `DrinkSupplierRole` has (or belongs to) one Drink, Supplier and Role. If you setup a unique constraint on the table as a combination of the 3 ids, then you can add as many instances as is allowed, much like a `belongsToMany()` allows. My 2¢ on this though, if you can get it working via `belongsToMany`, then 

Answer (score 0):

still not shure if I got your question right but if I do it might be as simple as ditching the roles table and make role_id a string (and rename it to role).

Another solution could be the use of constants or an enum so in your code it says reseller but your database still uses an int.

Cheers